# Accessing std out in makefile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, stdout

I'm running Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

I have an old makefile that used to work several years ago but has stopped working correctly (see below). Specifically, the command $(sudo docker create --rm wheel_img) used to return the container id (which is printed to std out upon execution of the command) but now returns empty.

Here is the start of the Makefile up until it fails:

```
    deploy:
        python3 -m build
        sudo docker build . -t wheel_img
        sudo docker cp $(sudo docker create --rm wheel_img):/tmp/xyz.whl wheelhouse/
```

In general it seems like using the syntax $() doesn't work as I expect it to. I expect it to execute the command and return the output.

For example, if I run

```
CONTAINER_ID = $(sudo docker create --rm wheel_img)
echo $(CONTAINER_ID)
```

it just prints nothing.

Was this syntax changed recently? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That never worked.  If you think it did you are imagining things :)  In makefile recipes `$` is used to introduce a _make_ variable, so you are trying to expand the make variable named `sudo docker create --rm wheel_img` and of course there's no such variable.  If you want to pass a `$` to the shell you have to double it, so this should be `$$(sudo docker ...)`

Comment: Also I have no idea what you mean by that example: is that supposed to be in a recipe?  You can't put make variable assignments like `CONTAINER_ID = ...` in a recipe; recipes are shell scripts and that's a syntax error in the shell.  But `echo` is not a valid make command so if you put it OUTSIDE of a recipe that's a syntax error... so...? when providing examples please make them "real" enough so we understand what was done.

Comment: @MadScientist turns out $$ is what I needed! Thanks.